# Facebook API in Javascript - FB.getLogInStatus is not a function

Tags: javascript, facebook

I've searched on this site for the answer, but none of the other suggestions fix my problem.

I'm trying to implement Facebook's API and then check to see if there's is a connection. I should get back 'no_authentication', as I haven't set up a way of submitting credentials yet. However, I keep getting 'FB.getLogInStatus is not a function' and I cannot figure out what I'm doing differently to everyone else.

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript>
FB.init({
  appId      : '-----',
  xfbml      : true,
  version    : 'v2.8'
});

FB.getLogInStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'it is connected';
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'not logged in';
  }
});
</script>
<div id="status"></div>
</body>
```

Originally I was using code from Facebook's quick start guide, but was getting the same error: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart
I've tried turning off 'Sandbox mode' in my developer account, I didn't have on in the first place.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I can't make heads or tails of this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try getLoginStatus instead of getLogInStatus?

Comment: about five seconds ago, I'm infuriated with myself. I'm used to Java in Eclipse where it informs you if you slightly misspell something.

Thank you for your suggestion though.